# Best Practises for syncing remote server and local machines in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, synchronization, local

I have been doing Laravel for a couple of years now. Currently, I am managing a system with Laravel 4.2 
There are two parts for this project:

1. **Local Offline Systems** with Apache running locally. This project is for rural Nepal. Thus, internet is not readily available all the time.
2. **A Central server** that receives & stores data **whenever local systems are connected to the internet**.

Data that need to be transferred include **MYSQL Table Data** and **images**.

I have completed coding and testing the system in local machines. However, I am looking for the best ways to sync data to the server **on click of a button** i.e. whenever a **SYNC** button is pressed, all data should be securely synced to the central server. I am dealing with sensitive data and would like to prevent any sort of loss of data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not run a cron which checks if remote server is running (ex: every hour) and makes the sync?

Comment: Hello @ka_lin Thank you for responding. I'm looking for suggestions related to data integrity rather than the process itself. Would a single API work best or talking to server after each query... etc... Hope I'm not confusing you.

Comment: You could make a job queue and make sync jobs which would be triggered after a db change...the good thing about jobs is that they are rerun if failed (connection issues) and you can configure how many tries it can make etc